# SQL to return rows when certain value exists in Json in a VarChar Column

Tags: sql, json-extract

I am trying to return only the rows when tags column contain "environment" value

Table: Data

Column: tags VARCHAR ( 40 )

```
{"environment":"prod", "version":"1:"}, NULL, {"environment":"test"}
```

My existing query extracts "prod" and "test" properly but still returns rows when "tags" column is empty as NULL

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN JSON_VALID(tags) AND tags IS NOT NULL THEN JSON_EXTRACT(tags, '$.environment') ELSE null END FROM Data
```

So I want my query to return only 2 rows, but it returns 3 rows one being NULL

Comment: which database system are you using
?

Comment: also always a good read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are using mysql/mariadb, if so, try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(tags, '$.environment') IS NOT NULL
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/kFG4rnU6)